# Join & create buckets - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use case here which I want to achieve using python pandas. So, I have 2 tables "Configuration" & "Transaction". The tables are as seen below. Also I have the results table which i want to achieve -

```
**Configuration Table :**       
Set_id  Entry_Type  Effective_Date
------  ----------  --------------- 
S1      IN          08-2000
S2      IN          09-2002
S3      TO          10-2004
S4      TO          12-2006

**Transaction Table :**     
Set_id  Entry_Type  Accounting_Date
------  ----------  ---------------
S2      IN          09-2004
S4      TO          07-2007

**Result_Table :**          
Set_id  Entry_Type  Effective_Date  Accounting_Date
------  ----------  --------------  ---------------
S2      IN          09-2002         09-2004
S4      TO          12-2006         07-2007
```

Step 1 - Group by Configuration Table by Set_id, Event_Type & Effective_Date

Step 2 - The criteria for the join is -

```
(Configuration.Set_id = Transaction. Set_id
And
Configuration.Entry_Type = Transaction. Entry_Type
And
Max(Effective_Date) < Accounting_Date)
```

Please help me with the same.

Comment: tip: join all of the records, then do the filtering later.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a `merge`, it will automatically align on the common columns and the default type is `inner`:

```
In [5]:

df1.merge(df )
Out[5]:
  Set_id Entry_Type Accounting_Date Effective_Date
0     S2         IN         09-2004        09-2002
1     S4         TO         07-2007        12-2006
```

After merging you can use boolean filtering for the last part:

```
In [12]:

merged = df1.merge(df )
merged[merged['Effective_Date'].max() < merged['Accounting_Date']]
Out[12]:
  Set_id Entry_Type Accounting_Date Effective_Date
1     S4         TO      2007-07-21     2006-12-21
```

Comment: Will it take care of the condition "Max(Effective_Date) < Accounting_Date"

Comment: When you ask for max I'm assuming you're looking for the largest Effective_Date value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge()`

Configuration table

```
In [117]: ct
Out[117]:
  Set_id Entry_Type Effective_Date
0     S1         IN        08-2000
1     S2         IN        09-2002
2     S3         TO        10-2004
3     S4         TO        12-2006
```

Transaction table

```
In [119]: tt
Out[119]:
  Set_id Entry_Type Accounting_Date
0     S2         IN         09-2004
1     S4         TO         07-2007
```

And, the result using `merge`

```
In [120]: ct.merge(tt)
Out[120]:
  Set_id Entry_Type Effective_Date Accounting_Date
0     S2         IN        09-2002         09-2004
1     S4         TO        12-2006         07-2007
```

Comment: Will it take care of the condition "Max(Effective_Date) < Accounting_Date"